# Google Maps Using URL Scheme , Source location showing Properly in Maps ,Destination location not showing Properly

Tags: ios, swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios, url-scheme

[image]

```
let destLat:Float = ((dictionry["Latitude"] as NSString?)?.floatValue)!
let destLong:Float =  ((dictionry["Longitude"] as NSString?)?.floatValue)!
let srcLat:Float =  ((latitude as NSString?)?.floatValue)! //Float(sourcLatitude!)
let strLong:Float = ((longitude as NSString?)?.floatValue)!//Float(sourceLongitude!)
let urlString = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=" + "\(srcLat),\(strLong)" + "&daddr=" + "\(destLat),\(destLong)" + "&directionsmode=driving"

if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    /*UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(Float(12.972442)),\(Float( 77.580643))&daddr=\(Float(27.0238)),\(Float(74.2179))&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)*/
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL)
} else {
    print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
    HelperManager.errorAlertUpdate(self, title: ShowAlertTitle, message: "Your device does not contain Maps.")
}
```

Comment: can you provide srcLat and srcLong?

Comment: @DarshitVadodaria please check below .                                              var directionsURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=\(39.190269),\(-84.359380)&daddr=\(39.1899),\(-84.3598)"

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this:

objective c :

```
 NSString *directionsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",39.190269,-84.359380,39.1899,-84.3598];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: directionsURL] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {}];
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: directionsURL]];
}
```

image is shown below:

[image]

swift:

```
   var directionsURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=\(39.190269),\(-84.359380)&daddr=\(39.1899),\(-84.3598)"

    if UIApplication.shared.responds(to: Selector("openURL:options:completionHandler:")) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            if let anURL = URL(string: directionsURL) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(anURL, options: [:], completionHandler: {(_ success: Bool) -> Void in
                })
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    } else {
        if let anURL = URL(string: directionsURL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(anURL)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mansi Dobariya , in browser opening correctly , trying to open with App Source location showing correctly , destination showing latitude and longitude values .

Answer (score 0):

It is showing correct destination, perhaps not showing the address for destination, and this is how google map is currently working. The map is not showing the destination address. You can test is by interchanging the values of `saddr` and `daddr` e.g.

```
let urlString = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=" + "\(destLat),\(destLong)" 
                               + "&daddr=" + "\(srcLat),\(srcLong)" 
                               + "&directionsmode=driving"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but still i am getting same issue in destination location name showing with latitude and longitude values.

Comment: You can't do much about it,  if you want address then reverse geo code and then pass the textual address in destination